# navigate to the element that has an id same to the data-id data attribute of the click element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently making a like "one page" concept web page and I came across where I want the user view navigated to the specified element that its id is equal to the data-id attribute of the currently click element.

navigation div (i prefer use div for my own requirements)

```
<div class="extend clear navigator">
    <div class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" id="tes1">Test 2</div>
    <div class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" id="tes2">Test 2</div>
    <div class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" id="tes3">Test 3</div>
</div>
```

and the content elements

```
<div class="page_content container extend clear" data-id="test1">Test 1 container</div>
<div class="page_content container extend clear" data-id="test2">Test 2 container</div>
<div class="page_content container extend clear" data-id="test3">Test 3 container</div>
```

so if click the div that has an id of "test1" then navigate to the element that has an id of test1 (scroll up/down, wherever that element located at that has an id same to the currently click element data attribute name data-id) Any ideas how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

To dynamically select the div with the `data-id` matching the `id` of the clicked element, you can dynamically select the div by attribute `div[data-id=" + id + "]"`

```
$(".navigator_nav").click(function() {   
    var id = $(this).attr('id');    
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("div[data-id=" + id + "]").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: its shown the element on top, how to make its view on center?

Comment: @CodeDemon if each div has the same height you can subtract a constant value i.e. `scrollTop: $("div[data-id=" + id + "]").offset().top - 50` otherwise subtract something like `...offset().top - $("div[data-id=" + id + "]").height()/2`

Answer (score 3):

Actually it will be much easier to do the opposite - have the `data-id` attributes on the navigation and simple `id` on the element you want to scroll to. This way, it would be accomplished by setting the `location.hash` to whatever the `data-id` of the button is:

```
$(".navigator_nav").click(function (elem) {
    location.hash = $(elem).data(id);
}
```

What's more, it'll allow you to create another navigation if necessary (you would not be able to to this with your solution as IDs have to be unique).

As a sidenote, if you did not have to use divs for navigation, there could be no JS at all:

```
<div class="extend clear navigator">
    <a class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" href="#test1">Test 2</a>
    <a class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" href="#test2">Test 2</a>
    <a class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" href="#test3">Test 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use anchor instead, ie normal a with href, which points to the id:

```
<a class="extend clear navigator">
    <a class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" href="#tes1">Test 2</a>
    <a class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" href="#tes2">Test 2</a>
    <a class="navigator_nav extend align_left margin_right5px" href="#tes3">Test 3</a>
```